# BroadCast Receiver in android versions greater then 2.3

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

Well, there are lot of threads on this topic but all are before the release of android 3.1.
Now broadcast receivers will not work until user manually launches the application, i.e for broadcast receivers to work, the application should be in running state not stopped. There are certain questions in my mind right now, specially about BOOT_COMPLETED receiver.

Why would they still want to have BOOT_COMPLETED and won't let application use it? I mean there seem to be no point in having it. When system boots, apps are in stopped state and no app will receive this event if I'm not mistaking.

And on the developer page I read this:

"The platform defines two new intent flags that let a sender specify whether the Intent should be allowed to activate components in stopped application.

```
1:FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES — Include intent filters of stopped applications in the list of potential targets to resolve against.

2:FLAG_EXCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES — Exclude intent filters of stopped applications from the list of potential targets"
```

Can someone please explain the meaning of it. Can I still receive broadcasts when my app is in stopped state? And how can I register such receivers in manifest.xml ? I know these flags are added in the code but can I do similar in the manifest.xml?

Answer (score 1):

Apps are in the stopped state if and only if they have never been manually launched by the user.  It the user has launched the app at least once, the app can register for an receive BOOT_COMPLETE messages at startup.

Comment: you mean once app got launched by user , the BOOT_COMPLETE will be registered? and will listen to this event even app is closed ?

Comment: Yes.  Once its launched by the user, the app is no longer in the STOPPED state.  Even if Android kills it, it isn't stopped-  it just isn't actively running.  That's why dozens of apps do use BOOT_COMPLETE.

Comment: but what about other receivers? can i use them when app is stopped buy using the flags that i mentioned ??

Comment: Anything in the manifest should be launched regardless of whether its running or not-  as long as it has been run at least once.  It's when receivers are registered outside the manifest that the app has to be running for it to work.

Comment: Yesterday night i tried listening to NEW_OUTGOING_CALL . it worked when app is running. then i go to settings and force close the app. then i make a call, nothing happens . . I was doing it on emulator Android ICS .

Comment: Notice the button in settings is "Force stop" not "force close".  That button does put it into the stopped state.  But there is a difference between stopped and just not running.  A better test is to install it on the device, run it once, then turn the phone off and on.

Comment: Can FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES be helpful ?i mean they say that you can receive broadcast even when app is stopped.Do you know how can i use it to listen to NEW_OUTGOING_CALLS ?

Comment: Only if you were the one sending the broadcast.  Those need to be included in the intent you send out.